# Myrkul + Palisade Giant how does it work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I was going through my cards as I worked on a [Myrkul, Lord of Bones](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Myrkul%2C%20Lord%20of%20Bones) commander deck and saw my [Palisade Giant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Palisade%20Giant). Does the giant's effect:

> All damage that would be dealt to you and other permanents you control is dealt to Palisade Giant instead.

work if it has been turned into an enchantment by Myrkul?

> Whenever another nontoken creature you control dies, you may exile it. If you do, create a token that’s a copy of that card, except it’s an enchantment and loses all other card types.

Answer (score 8):

No, [Palisade Giant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Palisade%20Giant)'s damage redirection effect will not work if it is not a creature.

> 614.9. Some effects replace damage dealt to one creature, planeswalker, or player with the same damage dealt to another creature, planeswalker, or player; such effects are called redirection effects. If either creature or planeswalker is no longer on the battlefield when the damage would be redirected, **or is no longer a creature or planeswalker when the damage would be redirected, the effect does nothing**. If damage would be redirected to or from a player who has left the game, the effect does nothing.

This stems from a more general rule:

> 120.1a Damage can’t be dealt to an object that’s neither a creature nor a planeswalker.